# How to get path to nextcloud app path in javascript

Tags: nextcloud

Structure of my nextcloud instance

```
/apps
/apps2
  /myapp
    /img
      icon.svg
```

I'm looking for a solution to generate a full URL to the icon from a path relative to `myapp`.

Answer (score 0):

I've injected initial state but should be a better solution

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/18/developer_manual/app/view/js.html#loading-initial-state

```
        $eventDispatcher->addListener(
            'OCA\Files::loadAdditionalScripts', function () {
                script('projects', 'filelist_plugin');
                style('projects', 'filelist');
                /* @var IInitialStateService $state */
                $state = $this->getContainer()->query(IInitialStateService::class);
                $state->provideInitialState('projects', 'project-icon', image_path('projects', 'folder.svg'));
            }
        );
```